# ValidationException - Member must have length less than or equal to 500

Tags: amazon-kinesis, snowplow

My Snowplow enricher loads data to a Kinesis Data Stream but Kinesis responds with error 400 and the message `Member must have length less than or equal to 500 (Service: AmazonKinesis; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException` and I cannot find this exception in the AmazonKinesis documentation. I also do not understand the message, 500 what, bytes? When I look at Kinesis within the AWS console, there is no setting set to 500 and also I do not see anything related to maximum sizes.

Can someone tell me what this 500 is about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the Enrich app is trying to write more than 500 records to Kinesis at once. The `PutRequests` action of the Kinesis API has a limit of 500 entries. This is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecords.html).

In your Enrich config file, you have [buffer section](https://github.com/snowplow/enrich/blob/master/config/config.hocon.sample#L171-L185), where you can specify:

```
      byteLimit = 10000000
      recordLimit = 480 
      timeLimit = 60000
```

A flush is triggered when one of those limits is hit, whichever occurs first.